# Can I use a power supply with different input/output voltage for router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, power-supply, voltage

I bought a Verizon g3100 router; it did not come with its external power supply. The needed cord has an input of 105-125v ~ 60Hz 1.5a and output 12v 3.5a.

I can't find exact cord anywhere but I found one netgear cord that is input 100-240v 50/60Hz 1.3a and output 12v 3.5a. Would this be safe to use or no because the input is different?

Answer (score 2):

Power supplies which work on 100-240V AC, 50 or 60 Hz, and output 12V DC at 3.5A will be compatible, so long as the connector at the end of the power supply has the same type of connector and the same polarity (puts the + on the same connector as the device expects, normally with + on the inner connector if the connector is a 'coaxial' or 'barrel' connector.

A power supply which is rated to work with 100-240V AC just doesn't care much what the input voltage is. It is designed to deliver 12VDC no matter what.

Another  critical factor is the Amperage "A"; you can substitute a power supply which delivers the specified amperage *or more*. If you tried to use a power supply with a *lower* amperage rating, *or* a different voltage, now that could cause damage.

Comment: Ok thanks a bunch for the help. So you don't think the cord will fry the router because of the higher input voltage? In the manual it says not to use one that exceeds 125v

Comment: The input rating is to show you that you can use the power supply within a wide range of voltage. It's unlikely you'll exceed those figures on a house power system. No one is about to build an adapter to connect it to a dryer outlet or range outlet, but it would work there too!

Comment: @PatrickTrauth This will be absolutely fine - it would be anyway, but particularly as the one you have has a greater input range then the original.     The router only cares about the voltage it receives and that the current is not less then what it needs.

Comment: The connector also has to have the same polarity.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone you are all life savers! I think I understand what you guys mean about the input volts and the polarity. Only thing I'm still unsure of is it safe that the power supply I was considering getting inputs 1.2a instead of 1.5a?

Comment: The Netgear replacement only needs 1.3A of AC power to deliver 3.5A of 12VDC power. It's _more_ efficient than the original power supply, which is AOK.